# Proving the quasiconvexity of a bivariate function

Tags: real-analysis

The function in question is $2x^2 + 2y^2 - xy$. I want to use the definition where a function is quasiconvex if the worse set corresponding to a given real value is a convex set ie $f(x,y) < c$ is a convex set.

Is it correct to write that if $x^2 + y^2 < c$ is a convex set then $x^2 + y^2 - xy < c$ is also a convex set since it denotes a smaller region within the previous region?

Comment: I don't know what the subject of this question is, but it is not set theory.